# Defer loading JavaScript in Symfony 1.4

Tags: javascript, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to optimize a Symfony 1.4 project and one thing that I would like to do is to defer JavaScript loading. I'm using the `use_javascript()` function to include files from inside templates.

Does `use_javascript()` have an options parameter (...or any documentation whatsoever?)

Alternatively, is there an alternative method for adding a tag to the collection for `include_javascripts()`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

you use `use_javascript('scriptname')` to specify a javascript file to load - this doesn't add the JS file to the page it just allows symfony to build a list of files to include .. then to include the files you use `include_javascripts()` so to be "efficient" just place the `include_javascripts()` at the bottom of the page ...

As suggested here (jQuery example)-> http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/18

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing at the moment. However the way I understand it there is a difference between placing scripts at the bottom of the page and using the defer attribute. In other words, deferred load waits until the DOM is loaded before processing scripts. Scripts at bottom processes the scripts last, but still before the DOM is complete. It's possible this doesn't make a practical difference though.

Comment: @anstosa - do you have a link to this info? I'm looking for a solid source on the difference between defer and putting scripts at the bottom of the page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `append_to_slot('javascript')` inside template. With [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) implemented 
Once development is finished and I want to deploy code for end users, require.js optimizer can combine the JavaScript files together and minify it for me.

I end up with single `.js` file included to the page.